# Filter table data by specific column

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am a newbie to coding when it comes to .NET or c#. However, I have been assigned few tasks to make enhancements in a current live project. One of the queries by the user is to remove all the entries whose status is approved.
Now, I know where to make the change but not sure how should I achieve it. Below is the code of tr tag which gets the data and views it in a table i would like to filter the below table to show data based upon a column isapproved which is false | 0.

Please try and help me achieve it.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="LogPendigSheet in PendingList | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse| filter:searchEmployeeName">
                        <td class="text-center pointer"><span title="View Timesheet" ng-click="ViewTimesheet(LogPendigSheet.EmployeeDomainName,LogPendigSheet.LogStartDate|jsonDate : 'dd/MMM/yyyy',LogPendigSheet.DepartmentName);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list ng-scope"></span> | <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check ng-scope" title="Approve Timesheet" ng-click="GetTaskLogID(LogPendigSheet.TaskLogID,LogPendigSheet.LogStartDate,LogPendigSheet.LogEndDate);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ApproveModel"></span></td>
                        <td title="{{LogPendigSheet.EmployeeDomainName}}">{{LogPendigSheet.EmployeeName}}</td>
                        <td>{{LogPendigSheet.LogStartDate |jsonDate : "MM-dd-yyyy"}}</td>
                        <td>{{LogPendigSheet.LogEndDate |jsonDate : "MM-dd-yyyy"}}</td>
                        <td>{{LogPendigSheet.TotalHours}}</td>
                        <!--<td>{{LogPendigSheet.LogStatus}}</td>-->

                    </tr>
```

Comment: Pleas share a [mcve]. Also `Pending` is missing an `n`.

Comment: From the looks of it, it is using angular and is not a c# problem

Comment: There is a filter already there `searchEmployeeName` may be look into that as well

Comment: @Ramesh my bad it is angular and i am not well versed with it. The filter searchemployeeName is a dropdown consisting of list of employees to filter from. I want the table to already filtered by the isapproved column while the data is fetched and shown.